# PHP database class - Managing two connections with different privileges

Tags: php

I'm just trying to master the art of using classes in PHP and have come across a concern.

For security reasons, I sometimes use two database connections in my application; one with read-only privileges and one with full read/write. Unfortunately, I wasn't really thinking about this when I started to build a few classes.

So, I have a database class, which is essentially a pointless PDO wrapper (pointless because PDO *is* a wrapper), but thought it'd be good practice to write one anyway and I may extend PDO later too. This is what I did:

```
<?php
class Database {

    private $dbh;

    public function __construct($accessLevel = NULL, $credentials = NULL) {
        if (gettype($credentials) === 'array') {
            $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$credentials['dbHost'].';dbname='.$credentials['dbName'];
            $options = array (
                PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => false,
                PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
            );
            if ($accessLevel == "public") {
                $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $credentials['publicUser'], $credentials['publicPassword'], $options);
            } else if ($accessLevel == "private") {
                $this->dbh = new PDO($dsn, $credentials['privateUser'], $credentials['privatePassword'], $options);
            }
        }
    }

    // other database functions

}
?>
```

For a public connection (read/write), I simply used this:

```
$db = new Database('public', config['dbConfig']);
```

... or for a private connection (read-only), I used this:

```
$db = new Database('private', config['dbConfig']);
```

... and when I wanted to use the connection in another class, I simply injected the connection, like so:

```
$user = new User($db);
```

Works fine, but then I realised that I may need two connections inside that class, one for reading only and one for all. So I got a little confused, but had a go regardless. This is what I did:

Instead of calling the class with either of the connections, I called the class twice with both, like so:

```
$publicDB = new Database('public', $config['db']);
$privateDB = new Database('private', $config['db']);
```

and then injected both of those to my other class:

```
$user = new User($publicDB, $privateDB);
```

Inside this User class, this how I used the two connections:

```
<?php
class User {

    private $dbh;
    private $dbhp;

    public function __construct($publicDatabase = NULL, $privateDatabase = NULL) {
        $this->dbh = $publicDatabase;
        $this->dbhp = $privateDatabase;
    }

    public function doSomething() {
        $this->dbh->query("INSERT INTO......");
        $this->dbh->execute();
    }

    public function doSomethingSafely() {
        $this->dbhp->query("SELECT * FROM......");
        $results = $this->dbhp->resultset();
    }
}
?>
```

Right, this actually works fine but I'm worried it's not the acceptable method or it may cause problems later down the road. I have a few questions:

1. Is using two connections with different privileges still considered good practice? Even though I'm properly escaping and validating my data and binding the values using PDO?
2. If yes for above, is there a better way to manage the two connections for using in many classes or is what I have done acceptable?

Comment: "Is using two connections with different privileges still considered good practice?" - for the same data? Why on earth would that ever be good practice? You're adding a ridiculous amount of overhead for seemingly no good reason.

Comment: @CollinGrady, not the same data, no. I use the read-only privileged connection for all select queries and use the read/write connection for all insert, update and delete queries. This, I presume, was a method used to stop people injecting SQL and altering the database. If they didn't have permission but managed to inject SQL, minimal harm could be inflicted apart from selecting records.

Comment: Then it is the same data, just different operations on it; I don't see that as good practice.

Comment: However, if you really wanted to do so, I would make your database class have `read()` and `write()` functions, instead of carrying around two instances of it; then you just pass one db object around and functions `$db->read()` or `$db->write()` as needed

Comment: I don't agree that there's no good reason to have separate connections.  Take for example the possibility of an SQL injection attack against a search field, a login form, or even a page ID field in the URL.  If the query is only run via a read-only connection there's no possibility of running a query that can have disastrous effects.  You'd not be protected from data ex-filtration so it's no excuse for not handling incoming data properly, but it limits the exposure.